# C - Error with mallocing a string

Tags: c, malloc

I keep getting the following errors when i try to compile my code below. I searched online for what the errors meant but nothing seemed to fit my code. Please could someone tell me where im going wrong in malllocing a string below. I want to make 5 units in that array, and this is the first one.

Errors:

```
assignment4.c: In function ‘readFile’:
assignment4.c:42:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

assignment4.c:44:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

Code:

```
void readFile()
{
    char * listofdetails; 

    listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    listofdetails[1] = "cars";

    printf("%s \n", listofdetails[1]);

    free(listofdetails);
}
```

Comment: `listofdetails[1]` is only a single character

Comment: BTW, if compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using `gcc -Wall -g`  you would got a warning, and could debug your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: And they would just get undefined behavior that they would equally not understand.

Comment: If you're trying to create a list of strings, you need to do `char **listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 40);`

Comment: Some things to keep in mind: If you are going to use `sizeof`  in `malloc` calls, do yourself a favour, and use `var = malloc(40 * sizeof *var);`. Arrays are zero-indexed: `var[1]` points to the second element in the array, not the first. Lastly: C can't assign strings using `=`, you'll have to use `strncpy` or `strncat`, which requires the `string.h` header

Comment: If it even worked, why `listofdetails[1]` and not `listofdetails[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `strcpy` (don't forget to `#include <string.h>`):

```
strcpy(listofdetails, "cars");
```

Also, `"%s"`, expects a string, not a `char`, if you want to print a string

```
printf("%s \n", listofdetails);
```

is what you want.

If you want to print the first character in the string:

```
printf("%c \n", listofdetails[0]);
```

But if you want a list of details (as the name suggests), you need to reserve space for the list of n string `(char **)`, and for each string `(char *)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *strdup(const char *);

int main(void)
{
    char **listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(*listofdetails) * 40);
    if (listofdetails == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    listofdetails[0] = strdup("cars");
    if (listofdetails[0] == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s\n", listofdetails[0]);
    free(listofdetails[0]);
    free(listofdetails);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `strdup` is not part of the standard (but is available on many implementations).

Finally, if those strings are known at compile time you don't need to use `malloc` at all:

```
const char *listofdetails[] = {
    "cars", 
    "trucks",
    "motorcycles",
    /* etc */
};
```

Comment: How would i use this to include listofdetails[1] and not just listofdetails cause i want it to be the first element of my array.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines

```
char * listofdetails; 
listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
```

can be written as

```
char * listofdetails = malloc(40);
```

(`sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1). Still you should not use *magic numbers* as 40 directly in the code but use aptly named constant

```
#define STRING_LENGTH 40
```

The line

```
listofdetails[1] = "cars";
```

is wrong, since the left side is the second character location in the list of details, and you try to assign a string character to it. Use

```
strcpy(listofdetails, "cars");
```

and the same problem in the line

```
printf("%s \n", listofdetails[1]);
```

Use

```
printf("%s \n", listofdetails);
```

instead.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `malloc(sizeof(char)*40);`. It is called self-documenting code. But as you say, the magic number should be replaced with something else.

Comment: But i want it to be the first element in my array, which is why im using listofdeatils[1]. Im going to add a loop when listofdeatils[2] and so on will be added. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: @user3753834 First of all in C arrays starts with 0 not 1, so listofdetails[1] is the second element not the first one. If you want array of strings use array of strings - in your code you have array of characters not strings. I guess you can find a lot of array of string examples on the internet.

Comment: @Lundin: I would favour the use of `malloc(40 * sizeof *listofdetails)` instead of `sizeof(char)`, simply because the OP is probably trying to allocate an array of strings, not a single string

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a string to a single byte location.

```
listofdetails[1] = "cars"; //  Problem
```

where `listofdetails[1]` indicates a single character in a character array.

You should not assign string like above. use `strcpy`-

```
strcpy(listofdetails,"cars");
```

Else you can assign like this also

```
char *listofdetails = "cars";
```

It does not require memory allocation.

Try the below changes-

```
void readFile()
{
    char * listofdetails; 

    listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    strcpy(listofdetails,"cars");

    printf("%s \n", listofdetails);

    free(listofdetails);
}
```

Use `string.h` and `stdlib.h` header file also.

Answer (score 0):

`listofdetails[1]` is char(or int) type.  `%s` expects a `char *` type.  The fix:

```
printf("%s \n", listofdetails);
```

If you want to print out `listofdetails[1]`, then use `%c`:

```
printf("%c \n", listofdetails[1]);
```

---

`listofdetails[1] = "cars";` tries to assign a `char` array to a char(or int).

Instead, you can do:

```
listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
strcpy(listofdetails, "cars");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you want a *list* of strings, but you're declaration of `listofdetails` is only a *single* string.

Instead, you need to add another pointer, like so:

```
char **listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 40);
```

*Now* you can use `listofdetails` as you intend. Please note, however, that in C, array indexes start at 0, not 1. So you probably want to use `listofdetails[0] = "cars";` to set the first element of your array.

Answer (score 0):

a `char` is a single character (e.g. 'a')

`char*` is a pointer. in your case you allocate 40 (single) characters (malloc) and assign the address of the first to `listofdetails`. use `strcpy`, as Alter Mann wrote, to copy a string literal or any null-terminated sequence of chars to your `listofdetails`. to complete Alter Mann's example:

```
char * listofdetails;
listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
strcpy(listofdetails, "cars"); // make sure that the string on the right does not exceed 40 characters!
printf("%s\n", listofdetails); // will print "cars" on a single line
free(listofdetails);
```

example for array of strings:

```
char ** listofdetails;
listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARRAYSIZE);
listofdetails[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * STRBUFFERSIZE);
strcpy(listofdetails[0], "cars");
printf("%s\n", listofdetails[0]);
free(listofdetails[0]); // delete string
free(listofdetails); // delete string-array
```

Comment: I wanted to make a loop, so which would copy a string into listofdeatils[2],listofdeatils[3],listofdeatils[4],listofdeatils[5]. Is there anyway to do that? The 2,3,4,5 are the elements of the arry

Comment: in this case you need an array of array of characters, edited post

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how that would look?

Answer (score 0):

> assignment4.c:42:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

comes from the line

```
listofdetails[1] = "cars";
```

`listofdetails` is an expression of type `char *`; `listofdetails[1]` is an expression of type `char`, which is an integral type, and it evaluates to the second element of the array that `listofdetails` points to.  `"cars"` is an expression of type `char *` (more on that later), and you can't assign pointer values to integers without a cast.

This boils down to what `listofdetails` is supposed to store.  Is it suposed to store a single string?  If so, then you would need to write

```
strcpy( listofdetails, "cars" );
```

in order to copy the contents of the string literal `"cars"` to the memory `listofdetails` points to.

If it's supposed to store a *pointer* to an existing string or string literal, then you would skip the `malloc` step altogether and simply write

```
char *listofdetails = "cars";
```

The string literal `"cars"` is stored as a 5-element array of `char` such that it is allocated when the program starts up and released when the program exits.  An array expression will be converted ("decay") to a pointer expression unless it is the operand of the unary `&` or `sizeof` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration.

In the case above, `"cars"` isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and it isn't being used to initialize an *array* of `char`, so it decays to a `char *`, and its value is the address of the first character in the string.  So by the time this is done, `listofdetails` points to the string literal `"cars"`.

If it's supposed to store a *list* of pointers to strings, then you would need to do the following:

```
char **listofdetails = malloc( sizeof *listofdetails * 40 ); // note extra level of indirection
```

This will allocate enough memory to store 40 *pointers to `char`*; since the type of `listofdetails` is `char **`, the type of `listofdetails[1]` will be `char *`, so the following lines will work as you intend:

```
listofdetails[1] = "cars";
printf("%s \n", listofdetails[i] );
```

Making that last change will fix

> assignment4.c:44:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

which is complaining about

```
printf("%s \n", listofdetails[1] );
```

since as currently written, `listofdetails[1]` has type `char`, which is promoted to `int` since `printf` is a variadic function, and `%s` expects the corresponding argument to have type `char *`.

One more thing; in C, arrays are 0-origin, so you'd use the index `0` to access the first element of the list, and index `39` to access the last one.